# How to convert time string into hourly data?

Tags: python, date

I have a pandas dataframe of energy demand vs. time:

```
                 0      1
0   20201231T23-07  39815
1   20201231T22-07  41387
2   20201231T21-07  42798
3   20201231T20-07  44407
4   20201231T19-07  45612
5   20201231T18-07  44920
6   20201231T17-07  42617
7   20201231T16-07  41454
8   20201231T15-07  41371
9   20201231T14-07  41793
10  20201231T13-07  42298
11  20201231T12-07  42740
12  20201231T11-07  43185
13  20201231T10-07  42999
14  20201231T09-07  42373
15  20201231T08-07  41273
16  20201231T07-07  38909
17  20201231T06-07  37099
18  20201231T05-07  36022
19  20201231T04-07  35880
20  20201231T03-07  36305
21  20201231T02-07  36988
22  20201231T01-07  38166
23  20201231T00-07  40167
24  20201230T23-07  42624
25  20201230T22-07  44777
26  20201230T21-07  46205
27  20201230T20-07  47324
28  20201230T19-07  48011
29  20201230T18-07  46995
30  20201230T17-07  44902
31  20201230T16-07  44134
32  20201230T15-07  44228
33  20201230T14-07  44813
34  20201230T13-07  45187
35  20201230T12-07  45622
36  20201230T11-07  45831
37  20201230T10-07  45832
38  20201230T09-07  45476
39  20201230T08-07  44145
40  20201230T07-07  41650
```

I need to convert the time column into hourly data. I know that Python has some tools that can convert dates directly, is there one I could use here or will I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Well just to obtain a time string you could use `str.replace`:

```py
df["time"] = df["0"].str.replace(r'^\d{8}T(\d{2})-(\d{2})$', r'\1:\2')
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what the -07 means but you can turn the string to datetime by doing:

```
import pandas as pd    
import datetime as dt

df['0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['0'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

df
       0      1
0   23:00:00  39815
1   22:00:00  41387
2   21:00:00  42798
3   20:00:00  44407
4   19:00:00  45612
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the time column is currently a string you could convert it to a datetime using `pd.to_datetime` and then extract the hour.

If you want to calculate, say, the average demand for each hour you could then use `groupby`.

```py
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="%Y%m%dT%H-%M").dt.hour

df_demand_by_hour = df.groupby('time').mean()

print(df_demand_by_hour)
```

```
       demand
time
0     40167.0
1     38166.0
2     36988.0
3     36305.0
4     35880.0
5     36022.0
6     37099.0
7     40279.5
8     42709.0
9     43924.5
10    44415.5
11    44508.0
12    44181.0
13    43742.5
14    43303.0
15    42799.5
16    42794.0
17    43759.5
18    45957.5
19    46811.5
20    45865.5
21    44501.5
22    43082.0
23    41219.5
```